# Edit environment using nano

Tags: lubuntu, environment-variables, nano

I am new to lubuntu. I have installed java8 in my laptop. i need to set up environment variable (sudo nano /etc/environmet) i have entered the JAVA_HOME =" path" but i dont know how to properly save and exit the window. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME =" path"` - also, no space character before or after the `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Nano commands are listed at the bottom. the <kbd>^</kbd> character means <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. Thus:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit